# SyntaxError: missing ; before statement

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте не понимаю из за чего она вылезает все есть

```
m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
 if(groupIndex == 1){/* console.log('===Found match, group '+groupIndex+':'+match);*/ /*eval('ArrElem'+E+'_lvl_2['+I+'] = '+match)*/}
});
```

консоль работает а eval нет.Эта ошибка ссылается на начало строки но как понимаю это от eval
вот цикл в котором он задействован

Elem_lvl_1.output - 'css("background-image")'
E - просто число для динамических пременных

```
for (var I = 0;I <= Tag_L-1; I++)
{
var regex = /"([^"]+)"/gi,
str = eval('ArrElem'+E+'_lvl_2['+I+'] = Elem_lvl_1.tag.eq('+I+').'+Elem_lvl_1.output),
m;


while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
    regex.lastIndex++;
}


m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
    if(groupIndex == 1){/* console.log('===Found match, group '+groupIndex+':'+match);*/ /*eval('ArrElem'+E+'_lvl_2['+I+'] = '+match)*/}

});
}}
```

Comment: так какой именно код не работает? для каких значений?

Comment: Евал который в комментарии.Полностью ломается код когда убераю из комента .Когда он под коментарием,код функционирует нормально . почему такое происходит не понимаю.

По сути я тут в процедурный массив даю результат регулярки 1 группы

Comment: сделай пример, который можно запустить и увидеть ошибку, в вопрос можно [вставить сниппет](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/3525/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%80/3526#3526) который можно запустить и увидеть ошибку

Answer (score 1):

Вся проблема.Что данные которые я пытался запихнуть в массив были не в кавычках.Данные были bace64,а там как раз стоял ; получалось вот так

```
ArrElem0_lvl_2[0] = data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4A...
```

тоесть без ковычек которые определяют что это строка простите что побеспокоил за столь глупую проблему